# How to change method of selection back to box/rectangle

Tags: selection-tools, settings

I think I may have pressed some wrong button but minutes ago I used to be able to drag my cursor around and it would create a box for me to select vertices in edit mode. Now when I press down my mouse, it only selects the vertices my cursor passes through. I miss the box/rectangle selection option so how can I convert it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press and hold down on the [*Select Style*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/interface/selecting.html#tool-select-box) for the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep pressing <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle between the various selection methods. The icon will change each time you press it.